# Issue adding a background image on cocos2d-x Android

Tags: android, background, cocos2d-x

[image]I am trying to add an image background this way:

```
background = CCSprite.sprite("filename.png");
background.setAnchorPoint(CGPoint.ccp(0.5f,0.0f));
background.setPosition(width/2, background.getContentSize().height);
layer.backgroundLayer.addChild(background);
```

The problem is that the added background is weird and some parts are stretched. Please I need help how to add background properly. Thanks in advance.

To explain more please look at the original image and the result

Original:

Result:

[image]

Config code

```
    @Override
public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState)
{
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    mContext = getApplicationContext();
    requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_NO_TITLE);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_FULLSCREEN);
    getWindow().setFlags(WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON, WindowManager.LayoutParams.FLAG_KEEP_SCREEN_ON);

    _glSurfaceView = new CCGLSurfaceView(this);
    setContentView(_glSurfaceView);
}

@Override
public void onStart()
{
    super.onStart();

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().attachInView(_glSurfaceView);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDeviceOrientation(CCDirector.kCCDeviceOrientationPortrait);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setDisplayFPS(true);

    CCDirector.sharedDirector().setAnimationInterval(1.0f / 60.0f);

    CCScene scene = HelloWorldLayer.scene();
    CCDirector.sharedDirector().runWithScene(scene);
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
    For landscape Mode you can try this in your AppDelegate Class
```

Then apply sprite position

```
// initialize director
        director = CCDirector::sharedDirector();
        EGLView  = CCEGLView::sharedOpenGLView();

        director->setOpenGLView(EGLView);


        CCSize screenSize = EGLView->getFrameSize();
        CCSize designSize = CCSizeMake(800, 480);
        EGLView->setDesignResolutionSize(designSize.width,designSize.height, kResolutionExactFit);


        if(screenSize.height > 480 && screenSize.height < 720 )
        {

            CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(960, 540);
            director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
            CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Karboon=%f",resourceSize.width/screenSize.width);
        }


        else if (screenSize.height >= 720 && screenSize.height < 800)
        {

            CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1280, 720);
            director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
            CCLog("Resolution Scale OF NOTE=%f",resourceSize.width/screenSize.width);

        }

        else if(screenSize.height > 800)
        {
            CCSize resourceSize = CCSizeMake(1920, 1080);
            director->setContentScaleFactor(resourceSize.height/screenSize.height);
            CCLog("Resolution Scale OF Nexus=%f",resourceSize.width/screenSize.width);

        }

        else
        {


         director->setContentScaleFactor(1);
        CCLog("Resolution Scale OF S Advance=%f");

        }
```

Comment: For portrait mode you have to change screenSize.height to screenSize.width and swap width and height in CCSizeMake()

Comment: kandoi.sumit@gmail.com

Comment: amine.jebabli@gmail.com

Comment: I send it three hours earlier via wetransfer.. come on hangout if you could

Answer (score 0):

You can do such a way

```
CCSize s = CCDirector::sharedDirector()->getWinSize();
float w = s.width;
float h = s.height;
CCSprite *bg = CCSprite::create("shop_bg.jpg");
bg->setPosition(ccp(s.width/2, s.height/2));
```

Comment: Singhak thx for the answer. but the problem is not the size, I edited my question, please take a look

Comment: @Vervatovskis what is problem

Comment: @Vervatovskis may be due to some setting in the Appdeleget.cpp file

Comment: can i see your Appdeleget.cpp file